# Rebinding Super key shortcut in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: shortcut-keys

In Ubuntu 12.10, <kbd>Super</kbd> key is binded to Dash Home and to show all open windows I have to press <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>.

How can I change the shortcuts (I want to show all open windows by only pressing <kbd>Super</kbd>)? In the Ubuntu keyboard settings there is no such binding.